# Do nutritional facts take into account the inedible parts of certain foods?

Tags: nutrition, food, nutrition-information

I was wondering if the caloric values of leftovers of certain foods (may the best example be bones, when eating chicken) that are never eaten, taken into account when calculating nutrition values of prepared meals. Most importantly when vendor/food outlet is obligated to put them on the packaging/leaflets.

I can't find a paper with detailed methodology of such calculations nowhere in the internet.

Comment: This is more of a legal question and might vary depending on the country, but don't overthink it. Calories are from what is intended to be eaten. If it says 100 kcal per 100g, it's 100kcal per 100g unless there is a scam. Really, it does not matter. Being a scientist, when I started, I also wondered such things. There is no need for it. Trust it and just eat like a normal person.

Comment: I'm quite convinced that caloric values are per grams of food, "as it is packaged." USDA Food Data Central will specifically tell you if a chicken is [boneless](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/?query=chicken%20skinless) or [skinless](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/?query=chicken%20skinless), for example.

Comment: It's done from the actual food components (At least in the US) - https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-food-manufacturers/

Comment: An attempt was made to re-open this question by removing the "nutrition" tag. It wasn't closed because of the nutrition tag, it was closed because the question is unrelated to exercise.